# An unparalleled problem on matrices ....

Tags: matrices

$\mathbf{Question :}$

Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than $1$. Let $\mathcal{D_n}$ be the set of all proper divisors of $n$.

Let $\mathcal{M}$ = $\{M_1, M_2, \ldots, M_n\}$ be an arbitrary set of real square matrices of order n such that it satisfies $A_iA_j = A_jA_i$ and $A_i \ne A_j$, $\forall$ $i \ne j$.

Also, for each $d \in \mathcal{D_n}$, the product of any of the d matrices from $\mathcal{M}$ equals a fixed matrix, say $\mathbf{N}$.

Then prove that $det(\mathbf{N})$ can take atmost three values, $i.e. -1, 0, 1$.

$\textbf{My attempt :}$

I confess I am utterly confused by this question. But the values $-1, 0, 1$ led to me think that if we can prove $\mathbf{N}$ is $\textit{idempotent}$, then we r done. Can somebody provide hints or solutions for this question please ?

Comment: The property that any $d\in \mathcal{D}_n$ matrices from your set $\mathcal{M}$ produce the same matrix $\bf{N}$ would imply that every $M_{i}\in\mathcal{M}$ has the same determinant. That should get you to your answer...

Comment: @Volk, But $d \ne 1$, as $1$ is not a proper divisor of $n$, so how can we conclude that every matrix $M_i \in \mathcal{M}$ has the same determinant ?

Comment: What if $n$ is prime?  If you exclude $d = 1$, the set $\mathcal{D}_n$ is empty, so the condition about $\mathbf{N}$ is vacuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider taking the product of $d\in \mathcal{D}_n$ matrices from your set $\mathcal{M}$. Then, according to your problem we have;

$${\bf{N}}=M_1M_2\cdots M_d$$

Additionally, we know that $d<n$ for all $d\in \mathcal{D}_n$. So we have some matrix $M_i \in \mathcal{M}$ that we can replace one of the matrices in our product with to produce the same fixed matrix. That is;

$${\bf{N}}=\underbrace{M_1M_2\cdots M_d}_{d\space matrices}=\underbrace{M_1M_2\cdots M_i}_{d\space matrices}$$

Taking the determinant gives us;

$$\det(M_1M_2\cdots M_d)=\det(M_1M_2\cdots M_i)$$

$$\therefore\det(M_1)\det(M_2)\cdots\det(M_d)=\det(M_1)\det(M_2)\cdots\det(M_i)$$

$$\therefore\det(M_d)=\det(M_i)$$

This game can be played with every matrix in the set $\mathcal{M}$, which yields;

$$\det({\bf{N}})=(\det(M_i))^d \space \forall \space  d\in \mathcal{D}_n$$

for some arbitrary matrix $M_i \in \mathcal{M}$.

From here, one can easily show that $\det(M_i)=\{-1,0,1\}$ from which your result about $\bf{N}$ follows.